# Nav and lists in a reset style-sheet

Tags: css, css-reset

Is this reset style-sheet correct? The problem I am having is with the oi and ul.

As you can see, below where there is

```
 ol li, ul li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 40px;
   }
```

I only want to apply it for Lists within the page, it worked, however It applys the style to the Nav list as well! which is in the header, how can I prevent that from happening?

```
html, body, div, section, article, span, figure, figcaption, img, 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, 
small, strong, sub, sup, input, output, textarea, ol, ul, li, fieldset, 
form, label, legend, tr, th, td, table, caption, footer, header, 
hgroup, aside, menu, nav, time, mark, audio, video, 
canvas, embed, iframe, object {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font: inherit;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

ol li, ul li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 40px;
}

abbr {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: how about  `li:not(.Nav )` or `body:not(nav) ol li, nav ul li {}`?

Comment: correct onlyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: That works well for modern browsers, but if you have to worry about ie8 or lower it won't work.

Comment: @spacebean you would normally have hacks for IE and old browsers...   besides they wont understand `nav` either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are `li` elements in your `nav` you have to reset them again or (a better way) you should specify which `li` elements should have these margins. so use a class for them instead.

```
 ol li.margined, ul li.margined {
    margin: 5px 0 0 40px;
 }
```

or the first option

```
ol li, ul li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 40px;
}
nav ol li, nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have chosen the first option, but it is not supported in all browsers is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a more specific class to override it, e.g.

```
ul.yourNavClass li {
   margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

That's assuming the class is on the ul element, since I can't see your code. If it's not, just change it to whatever way it is layed out, `.yourNavClass ul li`, or `nav ul li` etc.